# Kleisli category with equalizers?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I was reading Hosseini's paper on "Equalizers in Kleisli Categories", yet I couldn't figure it out an example of a Kleisli category with (all) equalizers with the extra requirement of not being equivalent to the category of algebras.
Look, for instance, that his example of sets and partial maps is equivalent to the category of algebras.

Comment: The Kleisli category for the free group monad has equalizers by the Nielsen--Schreier theorem.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell That sound like an answer, care to post it as one?

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell What are the Kleisli and Eilenberg-Moore categories for that monad?

Comment: The Eilenberg--Moore category is the category of groups and group homomorphisms, and the Kleisli category is the full subcategory of free groups.